# Can Screaming Frog check for invalid SSL certificates?

Tags: security-certificate, screaming-frog

I've been using Screaming Frog to test the home pages of a few hundred sites I manage, to see what status codes they return. I noticed in my browser that one of those sites has an invalid (expired) SSL cert. I cannot see this anywhere in Screaming Frog.

Is there some way in Screaming Frog to view information about the status of the security certificates of URLs, such as Valid/Invalid, Expiry Date, Issued By, etc ?

Comment: I use this script run from a cron job to alert me that my certificates will be expiring soon: https://github.com/Matty9191/ssl-cert-check

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That's an awesome script!

Comment: It would be better if it had an option to produce no output if nothing is expiring within X days.  To run it from cron I filter its output with a perl script so that it doesn't send me an email unless there is a problem https://gist.github.com/stephenostermiller/411fd6eca66346b6177064eb20ce910f

Comment: Nice workaround. I plan to ditch Certbot soon - most likely going to copy your setup

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Screaming Frog is not capable of this. If you're comfortable using a terminal you could use [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) though.

Here's a command that will verify the certs and pull the expiry date:

`echo "Q" | openssl s_client -servername [domain] -connect [domain]:443 | openssl x509 -noout -dates`

Example output:

```
 ~ % echo "Q" | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -dates 
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Los Angeles, O = Internet\C2\A0Corporation\C2\A0for\C2\A0Assigned\C2\A0Names\C2\A0and\C2\A0Numbers, CN = www.example.org
verify return:1
DONE
notBefore=Mar 14 00:00:00 2022 GMT
notAfter=Mar 14 23:59:59 2023 GMT
```

If I was in your shoes, I'd probably write a shell script to gather this data for each site and run it on a cron.

Comment: Always use `-servername` in `s_client` otherwise you risk not connecting to proper site as SNI won't be activated. Depends of your openssl version too (newer ones do that automatically for you, not older ones)

Comment: Updated. Nice catch @PatrickMevzek